# Install YAST package under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, opensuse, packages

How to install a YAST metapackage (.ymp) package under Ubuntu? 
Are there any tools for converting a .ymp to a .deb or to an installation script?

Comment: As a long time SUSE user, this is the first time I've heard of .ypm files. Do you have an example of one somewhere?

Comment: Your truth - not "ypm", but "ymp"

Comment: What do you want to install, there is a 99% chance of Ubuntu already having it as .deb. If not, there is another 99% chance that this package is so system specific that you don't want to install the ymp as it wouldn't work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `alien`.

See: http://www.howtoforge.com/converting_rpm_to_deb_with_alien
and http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/23/installing-using-an-rpm-file/

Comment: I told about ypm (YAST, OpenSUSE), not rpm.

Comment: Thought it was a typo.  Never heard of ypm.  But now I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to convert Linux packages to another formats for further installation.

The reason is not obvious: having a package built for another distribution implies that it could be built against different versions of its dependencies (shared libraries etc). Installing this package to another Linux system, which has different versions of those, might cause instability issues at least.